# Valid USA visa on an old passport of different type

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, turkish-citizens

I used to have a "special" Turkish passport, as a dependent of my father who works at the government. I have a valid USA B1/B2 visa on there. I obtained a new passport after I got a job, as my dependent status is dropped after employment.

The following website says

https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html

> No. If your visa is still valid you can travel to the United States with your two passports, as long as the visa is valid, not damaged, and is the appropriate type of visa required for your principal purpose of travel. (Example: tourist visa, when your principal purpose of travel is tourism). Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the visa) should be from the same country and type (Example: both Uruguayan regular passports, both official passports, etc.). When you arrive at the U.S. port-of-entry (POE, generally an airport or land border) the Customs and Border Protection Immigration Officer will check your visa in the old passport and if s/he decides to admit you into the United States they will stamp your new passport with an admission stamp along with the annotation "VIOPP" (visa in other passport). Do not try to remove the visa from your old passport and stick it into the new valid passport. If you do so, your visa will no longer be valid.

Special passport is unique to Turkey. It is given to government officials for their personal trips, so it is not a service passport in any sense. All of my trips are touristic.

Do I need to get a new visa?

Answer (score 6):

Whether a special passport is considered Official or not does not matter here. The text you quoted clearly mentions that both passports must be of the ***same type***, and yours aren’t. So the visa is no longer Valid.

> Special passport is unique to Turkey. It is given to government officials for their personal trips, so it is not a service passport in any sense

Just for the record, a Service passport would have been fine too. Both of the passports need to be from the same country and of the same type.

**Interestingly** Timatic does not mention that the passports need to be of the same type.

> A passenger may enter the USA with a valid visa in an expired passport, if also holding a valid passport of the same nationality. Transfer of a valid visa to a valid passport is highly recommended in all cases.

[Emirates Visa Check](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=TR&NV=Turkey&DC=US&DV=United%20States&h=74c219816eb18a0ab219852c2f2e0ec85548e)

However, I would weigh US State Department's statement more than that of Timatic. The description on [State department's website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions.html) is crystal clear:

> Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the visa) should be from the same country and type (Example: both Uruguayan regular passports, both official passports, etc.).

Comment: Correct answer. A special passport may have been a bonus for OP being granted the visa

Comment: I guess the rules have changed since I last did that. I was in a similar situation to OP (had a valid b1/b2 on one passport which was not a regular passport, but expired) and was able to enter the US twice with that visa using a valid regular passport (I queried the local US embassy on this via email and told me it was possible). However, I would believe what is stated in the state department website.

Comment: The text on the DoS website has been revised to remove the words "and type."