# I inserted a space between my first and last name in my passport, do I need a new US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

Do I need to apply for a new visa since I have inserted a space in my passport name (the name in the old passport and the US visa is RASHEEDKHAN, and the name in the new passport is RASHEED KHAN), or can I continue with the old one?

Comment: Is it about US visa? Different countries have different rules: some visas are linked to a person, some are linked to a passport. Do you have the old passport? Is it cancelled?

Comment: The US accepts valid visas in expired passports: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103124/can-you-travel-to-the-us-with-a-visa-in-an-expired-passport-if-your-new-passport

Comment: What *exactly* has changed in your passport?  Is `RASHEEDKHAN` written in the first name column, the last name column, or split between the two?