# Valid U.S visa in old expired and damaged passport

Tags: us-visa

The passport which has my u.s visa expired recently (I got a new passport). However, the old passport bio page is now partially damaged (bottom part with the signature and Expiry & issuse date tore out). The visa is intact with absolutely no damage. Do I need to apply for a new visa in my new passport???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traveling to the US with new passport, visa on the old one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36589/traveling-to-the-us-with-new-passport-visa-on-the-old-one)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to apply for a new visa. Make sure to take the old passport (with the visa) with you when you come to the US.

Source: US State Department, which says on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apheresis):

> Unless canceled or revoked, a visa is valid until its expiration date. Therefore, a valid U.S. visa in an expired passport is still valid. If you have a valid visa in your expired passport, do not remove it from your expired passport. You may use your valid visa in your expired passport along with a new valid passport for travel and admission to the United States.

The Answers to [this Travel.SE question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103124/can-you-travel-to-the-us-with-a-visa-in-an-expired-passport-if-your-new-passport) add that the two passports must have been issued by the same country, and must be of the same type.

Comment: I am so scared. I dont want any trouble with cbp when I arrive. The thing is, there is no answer to question on the Official U.S embassy-Guyana page. I called them today but they were not able to give me a proper response. I wad given an email address, so i sent an email and got a generic reply. NO HELP whatsoever. I need to be sure on the way forward since I have a U.S trip coming up soon.

Comment: @TiNiYo I added supporting citations to the Answer.

Comment: I have personally done this exact thing. I had a visa in an old passport, which was expired and in my country of citizenship, they invalidate it by punching a hole in it as well. I had that with me with the still valid visa, and my new passport, with no problems. I realize this is only a sample size of 1, but maybe it helps you be more comfortable with the trip.

Comment: That's good. I read that a few people had no problem after their visa had punch holes... but i think my case is alittle more complex. The bio-data page (photo page) is partially damaged, like literally tore out. 1/4 of the page is missing. My photo, date of birth and passport number is still intact tho'. No damage to the visa. So there lies the confusion

Comment: @TiNiYo Most countries do that for a passport renewal.  I've ended the US a dozen or more times with a via in a passport "damaged" in the same way you describe (and obviously with a replacement/valid passport without a visa in it)